# Android app/ssh addon for Terminal Emulator

Tags: ssh, terminal, android

Im looking for an app with ssh and certificate capability that is free (JuiceSSH is awesome but I need to pay for certificate ability)

I have done some research, many point to Dropbear ssh but I am leaving that as a last resort since there *must* be a ssh with cert app, I just haven't found it

anyone know of such an app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By cert, do you mean SSH Keys? You don't need to purchase JuiceSSH Pro to use SSH keys. You can import and generate SSH keys within the Identities section of the app (Main Menu -> Connections -> Swipe Right).

You can see a full rundown of all features included in the free version here:

https://juicessh.com/features

Comment: Apologies, i had my facts mistaken, i will delete this question in a hour